# why tcp is being displayed if channel is SSL secured?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, netmon

I searched and found no answer for this so thought it is worth asking here.
I have made my client-server(SQL Server) connection secured.It is working fine but whenever i am checking the data packets by using netmon tool i am seeing TCP protocols also along with TLS.
If the channel is secure then i should not expect TCP.It shhoud only show TLS.

Please have a look on screenshot below : [image]

Any comment would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a resource better explaining it but these ones:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879935(v=sql.110).aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879919(v=sql.110).aspx

implicitly try to say that whether you use only SSL or both SSL and non-SSL, the first connection will be made over the default TCP port. Afterwards, if the client requests an SSL connection, then the SSL connection will get started in addition to the default TCP.

By the way, I don't know if netmon is capable of but you can try using WireShark and looking inside those TCP packets to understand better what's going on maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am using Microsoft OLEDB provider so the link which you shared is irrelevant. 
In JDBC we specify most of the parameter related to certificate in connection string but in OLEDB we need to specify only Use "Encryption For Data" property.

Comment: Although the docs are indeed for JDBC, the basic idea is the same for OLEDB as well. The scenario is, you connect with TCP then request for an encrypted connection. Then the TLS gets into the scene. If the server is configured for a forced encryption then you still make the first connection through TCP and if you do not request for a certificate to move on, then SQL kicks you out. ("SSL can be used for server validation when a client connection requests encryption." see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx )

Comment: You mean to to say that even SSL is enabled the first connection would be TCP..i agree. But the question is i am seeing entried for TCP frequently even after the connection establishment.This is what my exact question.